# Rails Model name conflict with included gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

We've been mocking up our email jobs with success until we actually included our SendGrid Gem at the top of our worker

```
require 'sendgrid-ruby'
include SendGrid

class Notifications::WelcomeWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(email_id)

    emailAddr = Email.find(email_id)
    ...
  end
end
```

The problem seems to arise because SendGrid has the same model within (Email)

thus generating the message

```
undefined method `find' for SendGrid::Email:Class
```

I've tried calling Email via ApplicationRecord::Email to be more context specific but to no avail.

All the SO and other guides generally go with change our model name, but I feel like there must be a better way. To be clear we are running Rails 5 so I'm wondering if theres been an update in it to address this issue which I simply haven't found.

Comment: Do you actually have to `include SendGrid`? That seems pretty invasive.

Comment: Well, I suppose we have an option to build out our own library instead of using theirs. It was simply faster from a development point of view to utilize their Gem - it's up their with the option of making our model name different. I do pan to file a separate issue with the SendGrid gem maintainers.

Comment: That's not what I meant :-) To put it another way: what happens if you remove the `include SendGrid` line?

Comment: Dingding. Submit as answer so I can accept. You have saved me countless hours of work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`include SendGrid` it the culprit.

It adds all constants from the `SendGrid` module to the current module (which is probably the top level), so you can use `SendGrid`'s classes  without prefix, e.g. just `Email.new` instead of `SendGrid::Email.new`.

The downside is that it also messes with your existing constants.

You can either include it under a specific module:

```
class Notifications::WelcomeWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include SendGrid

  # ...
end
```

Then, `Email` resolves to `Sendgrid::Email` and `::Email` resolves to your top-level `Email` class.

Or you could simply remove the `include SendGrid` line and use the `SendGrid::` prefix.

Comment: For clarity to others we opted to go with removing include SendGRid and using the SendGrid prefix as that is much more explicit in the code when people review it.