# How can I prevent Ruby from targeting a gem's class instead of my class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, rubygems

I'm having an issue in a Rails codebase that uses the [official SendGrid gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/sendgrid-ruby). There are two separate instances of the same behavior occurring.

### First Example

I've got an `Engine` class:

```rb
module API
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace API
  end
  ...
end
```

I *used to* refer to that class in my routes like this:

```rb
mount API::Engine, at: :api, as: :api
```

...but I occasionally got this error: `uninitialized constant SendGrid::API:Engine`. (I mean "occasionally" literally; it seemed to occur randomly during development and a refresh would fix it.) So, I changed the line to this:

```rb
mount ::API::Engine, at: :api, as: :api
```

I thought that should explicitly target *my* `API` and not SendGrid's, but I still get the error occasionally during development when I'm working on SendGrid-related code.

### Second Example

This one seems even stranger. This issue just arose this week, and made me realize that the above example isn't an isolated incident.

I've got a `Response` class:

```rb
class Survey::Response < Sequel::Model Sequel[:survey][:responses]
  ...
end
```

And our monitoring just revealed this error:

```
NoMethodError
undefined method `[]' for SendGrid::Response:Class
```

... on this line:

```rb
results = results.pluck(:response_id).uniq.map { |r| Survey::Response[r] }
```

This example seems even more extreme, since we're explicitly targeting `Survey::Response` and clearly not targeting `SendGrid::Response`.

### Question

I'd love to know what's causing this, but mostly I'd like to know how to stop it. How can I make 100% sure that a line targets *my* class and not the `sendgrid-ruby` gem's class?

I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58558665/how-can-i-disambiguate-my-own-class-from-a-gems-class), which came to the same conclusion as I did in my first question, though this question's issue was resolved whereas mine was not.

Comment: [This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508464/rails-model-name-conflict-with-included-gem?noredirect=1#comment70223099_41508464) answe might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that a module was being included in the global namespace, and so its constants were polluting the entire codebase.

For example:

```rb
require 'sendgrid-ruby'
include SendGrid

module MyModule
  ...
end
```

Including `SendGrid` in this way can cause the issue described in my question. Including any gem in this way has the potential to cause a similar issue.

The solution is to only include modules where you must, for instance:

```rb
require 'sendgrid-ruby'

module MyModule
  include SendGrid
  ...
  # I can refer to Email here, and it will target SendGrid::Email
  ...
end
```

... or even better, don't include the module at all, and instead explicitly refer to the module's classes:

```rb
require 'sendgrid-ruby'

module MyModule
  ...
  # Instead of referring to Email, I must explicitly refer to SendGrid::Email
  ...
end
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508464/rails-model-name-conflict-with-included-gem?noredirect=1#comment70223099_41508464) helped me recognize the issue. But since that question didn't come up for me in my searches, I'll leave this question and answer here for any future travelers.